# How to get ZeroMQ as a 32bit library and merge it with the standard 64bit library?

Tags: c++, macos, zeromq, lib

Installing ZeroMQ (v4.2.2) is a breeze with either `configure/make/install` or with homebrew, but only the 64bit version is available. I tried brew's `--universal` option, but it says a universal option is not available and so the flag is ignored.

```
$ brew install zmq --universal
Warning: zeromq: this formula has no --universal option so it will be ignored!
```

My question is thus, how do I get a 32bit library version of ZeroMQ?

And, if I have other projects that still require the 64bit version, how do I create a universal binary so that those projects still work as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Library files for ZeroMQ are installed in the standard `/usr/local/lib` location, but if `brew` is used to install ZeroMQ, symlinks are created to the `/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.2.2/lib` location. If you look at that directory, you will find `libzmq.a` and `libzmq.5.dylib`. Both of these files are 64bit and must be merged with a 32bit version.

If you download ZeroMQ from their website, you can change the `configure` script as follows:

```
./configure CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32" --prefix=`pwd`/i32
```

The `CC` flag and `CXX` flag tells the script to configure for a 32bit version ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261909/build-32bit-on-64-bit-linux-using-an-automake-configure-script)). The `prefix` flag runs the `pwd` command to instruct the configure script to install files to the user `i32` directory in the present working directory. `make && make install` ZeroMQ as usual and you should have 32bit libraries in the `./i32/lib` directory. You can rename these files to reflect their 32bit nature:

```
mv ./i32/lib/libzmq.a ./i32/lib/libzmq_i32.a
mv ./i32/lib/libzmq.5.dylib ./i32/lib/libzmq_i32.5.dylib
```

Both the `.a` and `.dylib` file must be merged to form a universal binaries, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120790/merge-static-libraries-into-single) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783453/how-to-create-a-universal-dylib-from-pre-built-dylibs-for-each-architecture). Start by changing directory to the location where the 64bit libraries are found, `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/Cellar/zeromq/4.2.2/lib`. You can rename the library files to reflect their 64bit nature:

```
mv libzmq.a libzmq_i64.a
mv libzmq.5.dylib libzmq_i64.5.dylib
```

Merging the libraries is via the `lipo` command:

```
lipo -create zeromq-4.2.2/i32/lib/libzmq_i32.a libzmq_i64.a -output libzmq.a
lipo -create zeromq-4.2.2/i32/lib/libzmq_i32.5.dylib libzmq_i64.5.dylib -output libzmq.5.dylib
```

Note that the symlink `libzmq.dylib -> libzmq.5.dylib` will still be valid.

That's it!